# with the Autopilot, "Wait for SimpleStreams to sync an image" activity that stays "In progress" forever

Tags: openstack, landscape

I use autopilot and landscape to install openstack, but "Wait for SimpleStreams to sync an image" activity that stays "In progress" for a long time (stuck at 99%). Here is part of the massages:

```
Oct 25 12:16:38 physical-hands liberasurecode[10498]: liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libisal.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 25 12:16:38 physical-hands liberasurecode[10498]: liberasurecode_backend_open: dynamic linking error libshss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 25 12:16:39 physical-hands object-replicator: Starting object replicator in daemon mode.
Oct 25 12:16:39 physical-hands object-replicator: Starting object replication pass.
Oct 25 12:16:39 physical-hands object-replicator: Nothing replicated for 0.0141232013702 seconds.
Oct 25 12:16:39 physical-hands object-replicator: Object replication complete. (0.00 minutes)
Oct 25 12:16:39 physical-hands rsyncd[23402]: sent 0 bytes  received 0 bytes  total size 0
Oct 25 12:16:40 physical-hands rsyncd[10551]: rsyncd version 3.1.0 starting, listening on port 873
Oct 25 12:16:42 physical-hands kernel: [ 2387.434470] init: ceilometer-agent-compute main process ended, respawning
Oct 25 12:16:51 physical-hands kernel: [ 2396.724377] init: ceilometer-agent-compute main process ended, respawning
Oct 25 12:16:53 physical-hands container-replicator: Beginning replication run
Oct 25 12:16:53 physical-hands container-replicator: Replication run OVER
Oct 25 12:16:53 physical-hands container-replicator: Attempted to replicate 0 dbs in 0.00685 seconds (0.00000/s)
Oct 25 12:16:53 physical-hands container-replicator: Removed 0 dbs
Oct 25 12:16:53 physical-hands container-replicator: 0 successes, 0 failures
```

Comment: i manage it after trying a few more times, but i still do not know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
Wait for SimpleStreams to sync an image
```

indicates that Autopilot is downloading the most recent cloud images for Ubuntu to pre-load them into your new OpenStack cloud.

If this does not terminate, it is an indication that there is a network problem. Also, keep in mind that these images are not small, if your connection is not high bandwidth it may just take a while.